# Ruby FFI how to define default arguments

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am trying to port [a native extension of ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/rinku) to FFI. The exposed ruby interface is

```
auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil, flags=0) { |link_text| ... }
```

and the block is optional.

There are two functions in the original c implementation:

```
int rinku_autolink(
  struct buf *ob,
  const uint8_t *text,
  size_t size,
  autolink_mode mode,
  unsigned int flags,
  const char *link_attr,
  const char **skip_tags,
  void (*link_text_cb)(struct buf *ob, const struct buf *link, void *payload),
  void *payload)
```

which does the actual work and

```
static VALUE rb_rinku_autolink(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
```

which deals with the default arguments and block callback stuff.

My question is if I want to expose the same ruby interface in FFI, which one of the above functions should be registered with `attach_function`, or should I define another c function for FFI? And whichever function to choose how to define the default argument values in `attach_function`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **neither**.  I think you are misunderstanding the point of FFI, or I am misunderstanding your post.  If you are porting your native extension to FFI, that should mean that you are getting rid of all the C code in your code base and converting it to Ruby.  You should convert the features of the old C methods `rinku_autolink()` and `rb_rinku_autolink()` into Ruby, probably a single Ruby method.  Then if that Ruby method needs to call some C functions you would use FFI's `attach_function` method to get access to those.

If that's not what you are doing, could you please explain what your actual goal is and why?

Comment: I guess you mean I should define a new c function named 'auto_link' which does the work of orignal 'rinku_autolink', and this function should have the same arguments as the ruby interface. Then how to express the default arguments in this c function?

Comment: I need a ruby method `auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil, flags=0) { |link_text| ... }` so that I can call it in my ruby code like `auto_link("go http://xxx .") {|link| ...}` and can call it like `auto_link("go http://xxx .", :another_mode, non_default_link_attr)` and I want to implement this method in c.

Comment: OK.  What's wrong with the way it is currently implemented in https://github.com/vmg/rinku/blob/master/ext/rinku/rinku.c ?  Why do you want to use FFI?

Comment: Ohhh ok.  Well then I would say that you should use FFI's attach_function on the C function `rinku_autolink()` to make a private Ruby method.  Then in Ruby, make a small, public wrapper around that Ruby method that takes care of handling default values for arguments.
`def autolink(x, y=3, z=4, &block); c_autolink(x,y,z,&block); end`